# EF4 Creating a custom DbFactoryProvider and other Db* classes

Tags: entity-framework, ado.net

I was attempting to create a set of custom classes to create my own provider that the Entity Framework would be communicating with.  I had created my custom class that inherited from the abstract class DbProviderFactory and had just begun testing to see if I could get it to talk with EF, but I ran into issues.

```
<configuration>
  <system.data>
    <DbProviderFactories>
      <add name="Custom Data Provider"
           invariant="CustomClient"
           description=".Net Framework Data Provider for Custom"
           type="CustomClient.CustomProviderFactory, CustomClient, 
           Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" />
    </DbProviderFactories>
  </system.data>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="AdventureWorksEntities" 
     connectionString="metadata=...;
     provider=CustomClient;
     provider connection string=&quot;data source=.;
     initial catalog=AdventureWorks;integrated security=True;
     multipleactiveresultsets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;"
     providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

With my CustomClient defined above I thought it would be smooth sailing into Entity goodness, but when my code attempts to create a new AdventureWorksEntities object I get the following exception:

InvalidOperationException
*The requested .Net Framework Data Provider's implementation does not have an Instance field of a System.Data.Common.DbProviderFactory derived type.*

Looking over the available overrides for DbProviderFactory makes no mention of an **Instance** member.  I'm not really sure why it is requiring this field if it is not part of the class/interface for DbProviderFactory.  Is the fix as simple as providing a field named **Instance** that returns an object of my custom type?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add this to your custom provider:

```
public static readonly CustomProviderFactory Instance = new CustomProviderFactory();
```

All build in factories have this - they are used as singleton.

Comment: Why isn't it enforced in the abstract class as a field that must have implementation?

Comment: That is a question for authors of the API.

Comment: There's no such thing as a static abstract field (abstracts can't be static). But, yes, it's a bad design.

Comment: Important note: you need a `public static` instance field - not a property